# Bypassing Chrome/FF developer tools security issue (enabling users to access hidden forms)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, security, authentication

I am trying to show/hide a form in my application depending on the user's logged in status. It should be shown if logged in, and hidden if logged out. This form is not a form to login the user. The user's login status is acquired through facebook login button, which is enabled through the javascript sdk.

I thought of showing and hiding the forms with two methods:

1. using jQuery to show/hide the forms by altering CSS
2. using ajax .load() to insert an html/php snippet holding that form

However, with both methods users could still be able to access the form using browser developer tools. With the first method a user who is not logged in could simply go into Chrome or FF's developer tools console and toggle `display:none` or `visibility: hidden` in the form's CSS styles. Then they could enter values into the form and still successfully insert data into the database table.

With the second method, it would be a lot harder but the user could still potentially insert HTML elements into the DOM (under the "elements" tab in Chrome) and reference the scripts I am running by looking them up in my .js files.

**Is there secure method of doing this client side?** I thought about using PHP sessions, however as I mentioned above, the condition of the user's logged in status is handled with javascript, and I'm not sure how I would integrate the simple conditionals in js with php sessions.

For example, right now the conditional structure for handling application flow based on logged in status is very simple:

```
if(response.status === 'connected') { // user is logged in 
       // js to do something, e.g. display form
       } else { // user is logged out
        /// js to do something else, e.g. hide form 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can never 'trust' input from your users. Whatever you do. With developer tools you can easily add HTML into a website and post the values to the server.
You could even edit the POST itself and add whatever data you want.
Security and checks need to be done server-side. You can simply use your jQuery show/hide and do the validation server-side.